# In this mongoDB code i have to find if their have drinks ordered is available in beverages. can i solve this without let can i take $drink in $match

Tags: mongodb

```js
db.orders.aggregate([ {
                         $lookup:{
                         from:'restaurants',
                         localField:'restaurant_name',
                         foreignField:'name',
                         let:{drink:'$drink'},
                         pipeline:[{$match:{$expr:{$in:['$$drink','$beverages']}}}],
                         as:'matches'
                         }
                       }
                     ])
```

Comment: "can i solve this without let can i take $drink in $match"   What happens when you try it?

Comment: no value returns , pipeline return empty so value of matches returns empty array, i am not sure but i guess The answer is:  to pass the pipeline into foreign collection we have to take the value from local collection, so we can do it with the help of Let , basically Let is used to specify a variable to use into the pipeline .

Answer (score 1):

Totally agree with what @rickhg12hs suggested, both directly and in general. Giving a more complete description about what you've tried, what was unexpected, and what you are trying to achieve helps us provide better responses.

To your broad question, yes there are alternative ways to structure the aggregation to achieve similar results. I am assuming that [this playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4a0w1-reJiZ) demonstrates your current approach correctly. If so, then one other way to do this would be to take the `let/pipeline` logic and put it in a subsequent `$addFields` stage to `$filter` the `matches` arrays that are generated:

```
db.orders.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "restaurants",
      localField: "restaurant_name",
      foreignField: "name",
      as: "matches"
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      matches: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$matches",
          cond: {
            $in: [
              "$drink",
              "$$this.beverages"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The above is demonstrated with [this playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CiwWiCGtBPL) that generates the same output as the earlier one.

But this begs the question of "*Why are you trying to solve this without `let`?*" Just because you can do something, doesn't mean that you should. Use cases like this are seemingly one of the things that the additional `let/pipeline` syntax was added for and it is more likely that it can take advantage of indexes more effectively than the alternative offered above.

So are you asking out of curiosity if there are other ways to do this, or is there a specific problem you're trying to address? For example, are you trying to improve performance, get different results, or something else? That reasoning would really be why you might consider changing approaches, otherwise the sample pipeline you've provided seems perfectly reasonable to me.